Group structure on unitary dual of $\mathbb{Z}_p$
Let $p$ be a prime, and let $\mathbb{N}_0$ denote the semigroup of non-negative integers. Define the Monna map $T: \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow [0,1]$ by
$$T\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n p^n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{p^{n+1}},$$
where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers, $0 \leq a_n \leq p-1$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.
For $l \in \mathbb{N}_0$, let $\chi_l: \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{T}$ (where $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle) denotes the character uniquely specified by $\chi_l(1) = e^{2\pi i T(l)}$. Let $\sigma: \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{N}_0$ be the function satisfying
$$\chi_l \cdot \chi_m = \chi_{\sigma(l,m)}.$$
Question: Can $\sigma(l,m)$ be explicitly expressed as a function of $l$ and $m$, at least when $l = p^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$?
The question came to my mind while going through the following article:
Monna, A. F., Sur une transformation simple des nombres (p)-adiques en nombres réels, Indag. Math. 14, 1-9 (1952); Nederl. Akad. Wet., Proc., Ser. A 55, 1-9 (1952). ZBL0046.05004.
Thanks in advance for any help, reference or helpful comment in this regard.

Not sure if this is helpful, but if you plug in $l = p^n$ and $m = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty m_k \, p^k$ (with $0 \leq m_k \leq p-1$) you can get something rather explicit. Let us distinguish two cases. If $T(l)+T(m) < 1$, which is equivalent to the existence of a maximal $0 \leq \hat{k} \leq n$ with $m_{\hat{k}} \neq p-1$, you get
\begin{align*}
    \sigma(l,m) \, &= \, \sum_{0 \leq k < \hat{k}} m_k \, p^k + (m_{\hat{k}}+1) \, p^{\hat{k}} + \sum_{k > n} m_k \, p^k \\
    &= \, m + p^{\hat{k}} + p^{\hat{k}+1} - p^{n+1} \, .
\end{align*}
If $T(l)+T(m) \geq 1$, you get
\begin{align*}
    \sigma(l,m) \, &= \, \sum_{k > n} m_k \, p^k  \\
    &= \, m + 1 - p^{n+1} \, .
\end{align*}
